# File object from Inputstream

Tags: android, zip, zip4j

I'd like to apply zip4j in my android app. I put a demo zip file into the assets folder (`main/assets/test.zip`). I'd like to open it with zip4j:

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
...
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("an/absolute/path/is/required"));
```

However, the constructor required for applying zip4j requires a `String` object (the absolute path of the file) or a `File` object. But the AssetManger of Android only returns an `InputStream`. Also please not: The AssetManger does *not* provide an absolute path or something.

So, what do I have to do in order to transform the input stream of `InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(filename);` into a `java.io.File` object which I then can apply to `ZipFile`

Comment: `file:///android_asset/` is the absolute path to the asset directory.

Comment: I already tried that. It does not work.

Comment: Any particular reason for the zip file to be located in the assets folder? Is it your intention to eventually bundle one with your app that way? Perhaps downloading/copying the zip file to local storage (from which you can then get a `File`) is an option too? Alternatively, have a look at the [`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) that comes with the Android SDK: it acts as a wrapper for any `InputStream`, meaning you could use it directly with the result of `getAssets().open(...)`.

Comment: Yes, `ZipInputStream` is exactly what I am currently using. `Zip4j` is probably not recommended for using in Android projects

Comment: Why? What does this package provide beyond `java.util.zip`?

Answer (score -1):

Quite a a common Task when dealing with assets:

1. Get a AssetFileDescriptor from the AssetManager : openFD(String fileName).
2. Get a FileDescriptor from that AssetFileDescriptor  : getFileDescriptor()
3. Construct a new File from the FileDescriptor.